# Tableau: How to use fields in Hierarchy on one dashboard and as standalone fields in another dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I have a workbook with seven dashboards.  On one dashboard I want a hierarchy for user drill-down.   However, on another dashboard in the same workbook, using the same data source, I do not want drill-down capabilities.  I want to use the simple fields in the row shelf but not as a hierarchy.

Example:
In worksheet-A, I have hierarchy: site, whse, posting period, item, customer.  All good.
In worksheet-B, I want to use these same fields but NOT as a hierarchy.

I have read how to duplicate the field names, but I would like to have the same column names on both worksheets.  There's where I have problems.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into similar situations. I think Tableau sees those dimensions as a hierarchy in the entire workbook.

The lame solution (but the only one I know) is to duplicate and just add one space to the end of each duplicated dimension name. That way it at least appears to be the same name.

Comment: Thank you.  I would not have thought of that workaround.  I'll run with that.

Comment: Good deal! Tableau is finicky like that.